# How to avoid duplicate primary key values with INSERT INTO SELECT and NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I am trying to insert rows into an empty table that store client information from another table. The primary key is ID and I use the following query to select records:

```
INSERT INTO client (id, name, surname, surname2, dob, phone, email, address) 
SELECT DISTINCT NVL(cl_dni, floor(dbms_random.value(10000000,100000000))), 
cl_name, cl_surn1, cl_surn2, cl_birth, cl_phone, cl_email, cl_address
FROM purchases WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id from client WHERE client.id = purchases.cl_dni);
```

My main goal is to generate a random integer for id if it is null and make sure that I don't add duplicate id values to the table, however it gives me an unique constraint violation error. Does this mean there is problem with the WHERE NOT EXISTS clause? How can use INSERT INTO SELECT to avoid duplicate primary key values?

Comment: What database engine are you using for this? Make the database `AUTO INCREMENT` these values, in that case you would not have to insert the id when you insert a new record because the database engine handles it for you. The unique constraint violation tells you that this id already exists, which means you have given the column the unique constraint. Why haven't you made the column (something like a) `PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT` (exact code depends on database engine)?

Comment: You do not compare to your newly calculated values at all.

Comment: I am copying these values from another table that is not mine. Each client has a random 8 digit id, so I actually need to insert the ids.

Comment: @PM77-1 i know i should ideally compare and i will definitely implement that. there is only one row in the original database where client doesn't have an ID so at this point I'm just assuming that it is not likely that I will get a value that already exists in the database. Also I tried hardcoding a number that I know doesn't exists in the database and still got the unique constraint violation so I think the main problem is the WHERE NOT EXISTS part. I will update the query with comparison, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the unique constraint on client table? Can I assume that there are dups in purchases table as you are using distinct while fetching the data? There might be a possibility that there are multiple records in purchases one with a valid client id and one with null client id but other attribute values are same. This way you are trying to insert 2 records in client table from purchases one with a valid id and one with a random value, but same attributes for the unique constraint defined on client table.

Comment: The only unique constraint on the client table is Primary Key. There are dubs in the purchases table because some clients made several purchases so the columns I am trying to insert into the new table (client info) are the same for those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Well random does not garantee unique, and the NOT Exists part will not find anything because the target table is empty.

Its not that easy in pure SQL but as you are using an Oracle DB you can easily do it in plsql. This should work in principle :) . Not tested.

```
declare
    iOffset pls_interger;
begin
--  Use max value as offset
    select max(cl_dni) into iOffset from purchases;
--  Use 1 if no id exists at all
    iOffset := nvl(iOffset,1);  
--  Loop thru all purchases
    for rec in (SELECT distinct cl_dni,cl_name, cl_surn1, cl_surn2, cl_birth, cl_phone, cl_email, cl_address FROM purchases) loop
        INSERT INTO client (id, name, surname, surname2, dob, phone, email, address) 
               VALUES (NVL(rec.id, iOffset), rec.cl_name .....   );
        iOffset := iOffset + 1;    
    end loop;
end;
```

EDIT
Another approach would be to find the max value i purchases and add the rownum to get a unique id. Try this, not tested...

```
INSERT INTO client (id, name, surname, surname2, dob, phone, email, address) 
SELECT DISTINCT NVL(cl_dni, mv.val + rownum), cl_name, cl_surn1, cl_surn2, cl_birth, cl_phone, cl_email, cl_address 
FROM purchases, 
    (select max(cl_dni) val from purchases) mv;
```

Comment: But as I fill the table doesn't it NOT EXIST compare the values against the values I just inserted?

Comment: Dont think so, the selected records will be inserted in a single step. So the records in the client table will not be visible before after the insert.

Comment: That makes sense. I am doing this for a school project and we haven't covered PLSQL, so I don't I can use it but thanks anyway! I will try to see if I can figure out a way of doing this in SQL.

Comment: Try the Edit approach in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best way is to create a sequence, starting at 10000000:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ID
     START WITH     10000000
     MAXVALUE 99999999
     INCREMENT BY   1
     NOCACHE
     NOCYCLE;
```

and make something like this:

```
INSERT INTO client (id, name, surname, surname2, dob, phone, email, address) 
SELECT NVL(cl_dni, SEQ_ID.nextval), 
cl_name, cl_surn1, cl_surn2, cl_birth, cl_phone, cl_email, cl_address
FROM purchases WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id from client WHERE client.id = purchases.cl_dni);
```

The problem of this approach is that you could generate with the sequence an existing cl_dni.

Comment: The problem is not the random numbers, even if I replace the random number part with a predefined value that doesn't exist in the original database it gives a unique constraint violated error.